# In $G/K(G)$ for commutator group $K(G)$, it is said that $[a][b]=[a][b][b^{-1}a^{-1}ba]=[a][b][b^{-1}][a][b][a]=[b][a].$ Why the first equality?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, derived-subgroup

Let $K(G)$ be the commutator subgroup. It is said that in the quotient space $G/K(G)$
$$\begin{align}
[a][b]&=[a][b][b^{-1}a^{-1}ba]\\
&=[a][b][b^{-1}][a][b][a]\\
&=[b][a].
\end{align}$$

Where does the first equality come from?

I only see that since $ab=[a,b]ba$, I get
$$\begin{align}
[a][b]&=[ab]\\
&=[[a,b]ba]\\
&=[aba^{-1}b^{-1}ba]\\
&=[a][b][a^{-1}b^{-1}ba]
\end{align}$$

Comment: In the *abelianization* $b^{-1}a^{-1}ba=e,$ because you mod out by the commutator.   Not in the commutator itself.   It's often not abelian.

Comment: @hawaiianearringgroup Sorry, I do not get your point.

Comment: Ok, by $K(G)$ do you mean the commutator?   Because you have a quotient there.

Comment: No, by K(G) I mean the commutator subgroup, i.e. the subgroup generated by all the $[a,b]$ with $a,b\in G$.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/87082/104041) is a potential duplicate.

Comment: I did not found this post very helpful.

Comment: That's what I meant.   $K(G)$, the commutator subgroup,  is not always abelian.   If you take the quotient,  $G/K(G)$, which is what you wrote,  you get an abelian group.

Comment: Yes, but I want to *show* that it is abelian. So why do I have $b^{-1}a^{-1}ba=e$?

Comment: Because you're quotienting by it.  That's what happens.

Comment: I do not understand that.

Comment: Look up "quotient group".  For instance,  $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z.$  How does it work?

Comment: It's not $b^{-1}a^{-1}ba$ that's $e$; rather, $[b^{-1}a^{-1}ba]=[e]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prove that the commutator subgroup,  your $K(G),$ is abelian,  because in general it isn't.

For instance,  $K(S_n)=A_n$, which is not abelian ($n\gt3$).

What you have above is the proof that $G/K(G)$ is abelian.   That's the *quotient* of $G$ by $K(G)$.  It's called the abelianization.

Since it's the first equality that bothers you,  just note that in this quotient,  everything in the commutator subgroup is set equal to $\bar e.$  But the commutator subgroup contains each $b^{-1}a^{-1}ba.$

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: @Shaun It does answer the question. the square brackets in the OP mean "equivalence class mod commutators'. so, the first equality is multiplying by the identity.

Comment: Well, it does *now*, @IgorRivin; it didn't before.